# Porque me dice que no existe el archivo que ya creé?

Tags: java, android

Estoy guardando una archivo en txt pero al verificar su existencia me dice que no existe el archivo. Me Podrían ayudar con esto porfavor.

PD: Es en la memoria interna del telefono.

Código Java:

```
        File file = new File("DePelisPeliculas.txt");

        if(file.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"Si Existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try
            {
                InputStreamReader flujoLecturaArchivo = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("DePelisPeliculas.txt"));
                BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(flujoLecturaArchivo);

                OutputStreamWriter escribirArchivoTemporal = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("Mientras.txt",MODE_PRIVATE));

                String linea = leer.readLine();

                while(linea != null)
                {
                    if(linea.contains(seriePeli))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        escribirArchivoTemporal.write(linea);
                        linea = leer.readLine();
                    }
                }

                leer.close();

                escribirArchivoTemporal.write(seriePeli + "," + tiempo);

                escribirArchivoTemporal.close();

                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"Guardo Archivo Temporal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"No Guardo Archivo Temporal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try
            {
                InputStreamReader flujoLecturaArchivoTemporal = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("Mientras.txt"));
                BufferedReader leerArchivoTemporal = new BufferedReader(flujoLecturaArchivoTemporal);

                OutputStreamWriter escribirArchivoPermanente = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("DePelisPeliculas.txt",MODE_PRIVATE));

                String lineaArchivoTemporal = leerArchivoTemporal.readLine();

                while (lineaArchivoTemporal != null)
                {
                    escribirArchivoPermanente.write(lineaArchivoTemporal);

                    lineaArchivoTemporal = leerArchivoTemporal.readLine();
                }

                leerArchivoTemporal.close();
                escribirArchivoPermanente.close();

                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"Guardo Aarchivo Permanente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"No Guardo Archivo Permanente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"No Existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try
            {
                OutputStreamWriter escribirArchivoPermanente = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("DePelisPeliculas.txt",MODE_PRIVATE));

                escribirArchivoPermanente.write(seriePeli + "," + tiempo);

                escribirArchivoPermanente.close();

                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"Guardo Aarchivo Permanente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ReproductorVideo.this,"No Guardo Archivo Permanente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si `file.exists()` te indica que no existe es porque en realidad no existe o no existe en la ruta especificada.

Si vas a leer desde el almacenamiento interno un archivo, debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + "DePelisPeliculas.txt");
```

Esto describe la documentación:

> **getFilesDir()** Obtiene la ruta absoluta a el directorio en el sistema de archivos donde los archivos que fueron creados con
>   openFileOutput(String, int) son almacenados.

El path obtenido por `getFilesDir()`, generalmente es:

```
/data/data/[nombre del paquete]/files
```

Pero puede cambiar dependiendo de la versión del sistema operativo.

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que me altaba era getAplicationContext().getFilesDir()

Comment: Excellente Erick! :)